# How can I display a google search api result in a div?

Tags: api, search, google-search-api

I'm trying to display the google search result in a specific div. It seems like there is a way to print the results in a different frame or window by tweaking 'target' property... but not in a different div.  Has anyone actually done it before... or know any tutorials available on the internet?

Comment: **See here more specific way**
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262020/how-to-include-google-search-result-in-my-specified-div-width-and-height/15263878?noredirect=1#comment21571964_15263878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html)

Is this what u want?

Comment: Sweet :) This may do it. Thank you!