# How to include google search result in my specified div width and height?

Tags: html, css, google-search

```
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." />
<input type="image" src="images/searchBtn.png" name="q" />
<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

css...

```
#searchResult{width: 1000px; height: 200px;}
```

How to do????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample which I have tried. try this.

```
<head>
<title>Search</title>

<style>
    #searchcontrol
    {
        margin-LEFT:500PX;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //<!
    google.load('search', '1');
    function DoSearch() 
    {
        // Create a search control
        var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();
        searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());

        searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("searchcontrol"));

        // execute an inital search
        searchControl.execute(document.getElementById("secrchBox").value);
    }
    //]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchcontrol">
        <input type="text" id="secrchBox"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=" DoSearch()"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

```
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<style>
    #searchcontrol
    {
        margin-LEFT:500PX;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //<!
    google.load("search", "1", { "nocss": true });

    function DoSearch() 
    {
        var ss = document.getElementById("secrchBox").value;
        // Create a search control
        var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

        searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());

        searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("searchcontrol"));

        // execute an inital search
        searchControl.execute(ss);
    }
    //]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchcontrol">
        <input type="text" id="secrchBox"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=" DoSearch()"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now default `css` will not load. You can customize as your wish.

Comment: @NewDeveloper- Yes! you did as my desire but it seems to submit then only shows next search form why?

Comment: @NewDeveloper- How could we increase or decrease the width of search result?

Comment: I have update my post. If this solve your issue, please consider mark this answer as accepted. :)

Comment: @NewDeveloper- Thank you very much as I got as my desire.

Comment: See this [Link](http://tutorialzy.blogspot.com/) and tell me could I place my search result below to menubar removing my contents?

Comment: Without working on that I will not be able to tell it exactly. But I don't think it is not possible to do.

Comment: This might help you. Check this;https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/an-simple-yahoo-api-example-for-new-api-developers.142718/

Comment: @NewDeveloper- Could we develop a search engine to search my website without using google?

Comment: @NewDeveloper- Ok! Nice I will learn more specific way later on. Thank you.

Comment: google.search API was deprecated and seems to not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

you put the `<iframe>`, `<script>`, or whatever Google gives you inside your `div`!

```
<div id="searchResult">Google code here!</div>
```

Comment: @shnisaka- sorry! i couldn't understand, but I need full source code of html , css...

Answer (score 0):

You may have three options. 
-The hardest one is to parse google result page. This could be done with php and some regular expressions work. If you are an experienced developer, this is the best.

-Second is to use googlesearch API. This one is very easy to implement. You can see how to do it [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started#JSONP). It supports REST calls, which are super easy to use. Pros: Relatively easy to implement, lots of documentation and examples. Cons are that you have an usage quota of 100 queries per day. Also remember that you need to get your API-KEY and register to use it.

-Third one, Include an Iframe. This is super easy to implement, just one line of code, but it's not clean and probably you don't want to have google's page inside yours.

Probably there's another one mixing a lot of javascript and Iframes, but, I don't see the point of doing that since there are many better options.

Let me know if you have any questions..

Thanks!,
@leo.

Comment: @lemil77- I want to do it with only css & js.

Comment: check this [link](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started#JSONP)  in the section REST from JavaScript. There's a basic example with html+javascript that you can use in your site.

Comment: You can get easily the API Key from [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) . User a gmail account to login.

Comment: @lemil77- I want input btn and input box as my desire?